# how we can get the nearest match using PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to see how we can get the nearest match of the given name by the names in database
This is the table with information:

```
-----------------------------------
id | Fullname   |  Email           |
-----------------------------------
 1 | Ramee John | Ramee@gmail.com  |
 2 | Ramee Tom  | RameeT@gmail.com |
------------------------------
```

> Ex: Posted name is **`Ramee J`** how to get the closest one which is
>   **`Ramee John`**

I have tried **`LIKE`** but its not working.

```
//POSTED NAME
$name = $_POST['Firstname'].' '.$_POST['Lastname'];

SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Fullname` LIKE '%$name%'
```

Comment: Do you have a `fullname` column in your table? Also, huge exposure to SQL-injection here. Imagine what happens when you type `O'Reily` into the form?

Comment: `where concat(firstname, ' ', lastname) LIKE '%$name%'`? you don't have a fullname field (or haven't shown it), so your query would be dead in the water

Comment: Are you looking for some kind of fuzziness as well? So if you search for 'ramea jonh' it should work as well?

Comment: Sorry guys I edited the question

Comment: You should always include the actual code you're using. Because the code you had first and the one you have now are similar, but different none the less. Is this the actual code you're using now? And how do you execute this query? Do you check for any errors?

Comment: @Qirel There is no errors about the code I have the problem is in `SELECT` value with `LIKE` because when I give the exactly name can find it but if there is changed couldn't find anything **EX: Ramee James should be selected but because I'm giving Ramee J couldn't**

Comment: Try to do a `var_dump` or `print_r` of your query and use that exact same query in phpmyadmin. Then you'll be able to pinpoint where your problem lies.

Comment: `LIKE` doesn't match for extra letters, just missing ones. `Ber` will match `Berlin`, but `Berlins` won't match `Berlin`, because it has extra letters. @Ramee

Comment: @Qirel Thank you I got it, I should write something different and find another way to get my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Fullname` LIKE '%{$name}%'"
```

Try this, but i don't understand why like doesn't work for you

Answer (score 0):

Table name and attribute names are case in sensitive mysql(in linux not in windows though) so try

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `Fullname` LIKE '%$name%'
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: Does not work, the problem is `LIKE` doesn't giving me the nearest name only if I giving the all full name.